# Pagination in No-sql database

Tags: redis, nosql, spring-data-redis

Does no SQL database's like Redis support pagination feature.
Use case : I have whole of customer data in Redis instance.However for my API ,request will be coming with pagination (eg :with paging size 10), now i need to load all of the data(lets say -10000) in my Application(Spring boot) from Redis and then do the pagination and return the relevant records(only 10).
However for SQL database's like Oracle it is much easier with functions like Rownum which help to do the pagination at the DB level itself and this extra logic is not needed in the application code .
Is there any workaround or better way in No-SQL DB's like Redis to do the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep your customer data at a **Sorted Set** in Redis. Sorted sets provide great features to sort data and requesting them between an interval.

Lets say, your data is loaded to a sorted set with their IDs. If you need to get 10 customer per page, just call the following for each page:

```
ZRANGE yourcustomerset 0 9
ZRANGE yourcustomerset 10 19
ZRANGE yourcustomerset 20 29
```

Please check [this](https://redis.io/commands/zrange) too

Comment: well do u mean i need to add each customer id to a (new)sorted set by incrementing the count by 1 each time as a score for this sorted set.Is it not extra data population in the instance .when my actual data is already being stored as a hash ?

Comment: No. You'll have one customer sorted set. The scores and elements will be exact IDs of your cursomer row like ZADD yourcustomerset 1 1, ZADD yourcustomerset 2 2. When you get 10 datas after your ZRANGE, you may use HMGET to get 10 datas from your already sorted hash structure at one call. It is not a high cost for redis. We do the same approach for 5 million data.

Comment: did you solve this ? If so, would you set my answer as the accepted one ? :)

Comment: I see a problem with this.For eg: i have new hash for every customer created.lets say customer:1,customer:2,customer:3 .As per ur sgstn i need t o create a sorted set,lets say CustomerSet and add each customerid as created in withwith score as 1,2,3 and so on .And query based on the elemensts in sorted set.However if i delete customer:3 from hash.i need to delete from sorted set as well.Now if i query sorted set there will be 1 empty space.hence the querying result would be inappropriate !

Comment: Scores are just for sorting. Your query will be executed by indexes of set. You are gonna use ZRANGE, not ZRANGEBYSCORE. So if you use ZRANGE CustomerSet 0 5 it will return 1,2,4,5,6. When you got this data set, you'll use just MGET to get customer:1,customer:2,customer:4,customer:5 and customer:6. Note that there is no 3 so there is nothing inappropriate.

Comment: and yes, you have to remove both hash and sorted set element when you want to remove a customer.

Comment: Thanks FTB...I misunderstood zrange for zrangebyscore

Comment: What if you allow the user to set custom filters to query only a subset of the whole customer data? The ranges in this case are variable and depend on the filters and their values (set by a user). How would someone implement a pagination in NoSQL given this dynamic constraint (filters set by user)?